# How to change Qt 5.9 virtual keyboard layout/locale

Tags: qt, qt5

There is an amazing thing - Qt Virtual Keyboard. There is a very useful example in the examples of QtCreator.
Everything works, but there is one problem - the language is only English (or rather British English). And I need also Russian.

```
CONFIG += lang-ru
CONFIG += lang-ru_RU
CONFIG += lang-all
```

This all I tried. It does not help.

```
console.log ("locales available:" + VirtualKeyboardSettings.availableLocales)
```

It shows only en_GB.

I'm confused. 
The only discussion of the problem was found [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/76802/how-to-enable-virtual-keyboard-languages).

And here:
[How to change Qt 5.7 virtual keyboard layout/locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40507390/how-to-change-qt-5-7-virtual-keyboard-layout-locale)
But the solution did not help.
I tried on Windows and on Mac - all the same.

How to add Russian localization? If it is possible give an example of the working code, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it has been months since you asked this question but I had similiar issues that I managed to solve. I thought that I will post the solution here, in case anybody needed it:

I assume you made the same mistake as me and set CONFIG+=lang- argument in your project (the project that uses virtual keyboard). You need to set it in qtvirtualkeyboard project instead and build it (create dll files).

[qtVirtualKeyboard project settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYvy9.png)

Then you can use the plugin in any project you wish.

Comment: Great! On mac os everything works fine! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you add:

```
CONFIG += lang-ru_RU
```

to the virtualkeyboard.pro file and recompile the project it will generate the qtvirtualkeyboardplugin libraries with the russian layout. Put them in the platforminputcontexts folder and that's it.